# Using a messagebox in a sub procedure to block user error in VB

Tags: vb.net

I've been trying to keep users from entering letters in a textbox. I tried using If statements to show a message box in case of user error, but the program still crashes.

The code line that is crashing is:

```
hours = CDec(txtHoursWorked.Text)
payPerHour = CDec(txtHourlyPay.Text)
```

I've tried:

hours = CDec(IsNumeric(txtHoursWorked.Text))

payPerHour = CDec(IsNumeric(txtHourlyPay.Text))

but this causes my calculations to be incorrect

The error is:

> System.InvalidCastException occurred

My full code is:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Public Class frmPay

    Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim hours, payPerHour, overtimeHours, pay As Decimal
        InputData(hours, payPerHour)
        CalculateValues(hours, payPerHour, overtimeHours, pay)
        DisplayData(overtimeHours, pay)
    End Sub
    Sub InputData(ByRef hours As Decimal, ByRef payPerHour As Decimal)
        If IsNumeric(txtHoursWorked.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Value")
        ElseIf IsNumeric(txtHourlyPay.Text) = False Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Value")
        End If
        If (txtHoursWorked.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Value")
        ElseIf (txtHourlyPay.Text) = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Value")
        End If
        hours = CDec(txtHoursWorked.Text)
        payPerHour = CDec(txtHourlyPay.Text)
    End Sub
    Sub CalculateValues(hours As Decimal, payPerHour As Double, ByRef overtimeHours As Decimal, ByRef pay As Decimal)
        overtimeHours = Math.Abs(40 - hours)
        If hours <= 40 Then
            pay = CDec((payPerHour * hours))
        ElseIf hours > 40 Then
            pay = CDec((CDec(payPerHour * hours) + (payPerHour * 1.5) * (overtimeHours)))
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayData(overtimeHours As Decimal, pay As Decimal)
        txtOvertime.Text = CStr(overtimeHours)
        txtWeeksPay.Text = pay.ToString("C")
    End Sub
End Class
```

What am I missing or doing incorrectly in my code?

Comment: try correcting this line `Dim hours, payPerHour, overtimeHours, pay As Decimal` to this `Dim hours, payPerHour As Decimal, overtimeHours As Decimal, pay As Decimal`

Comment: thx, but that didn't work either

Comment: And, for what it's worth, your problem is that if the user enters an invalid value, you tell them that something is wrong but then continue to try to use their invalid input.  You should stop processing once you know you can't use the data successfully.

Comment: I still can't figure this out I've tried looping it and everything I just don't understand.

Comment: There is a magic command to stop the processing before your calculation. It is Exit Sub . Just add that after the MessageBox on a new line. It might be nice to set the focus back to the offending text box.